# Display 3 tables using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

> I have 3 tables 
>   mentor,
>   board and 
>   intern

Im using this code but it doesnt display anything

```
$wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE status='active' 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM board WHERE status='active' 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM intern WHERE status='active'
");
```

Comment: Hi Dann!  Have you tried running your query in phpMyAdmin or another database connection tool to see if it has results there?

Comment: do you have any table prefix? or what you have written in `$table_prefix` in wp-config.php file

Comment: it is working whenever I tried to put mentor and board only....but when I add the intern table it does'nt display anything ....I'm using xampp for testing